# I need to grant access to use tables of one schema in another schema

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have an schema [A], which has a package in which a function calls another schema's[B] table [tableB]. 
When I compiled the package I got the error, "table or view doesnt exit" I googled and found that the error is because my package is calling another schema's table. 
Later I found that I have to grant privilage in the called schema[B]. In Schema B's  package I wrote the following code

procedure givePrivilege
 begin
 GRANT SELECT ON tableB  TO A;
 end;

Im new to Oracle and Im struck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As B, you simply need to grant A `SELECT` privileges on the table.  You don't need to create a procedure that grants the privilege.  You simply need to execute the `GRANT` statement while logged in as B.

```
GRANT SELECT ON tableB
   TO a
```

Comment: Yes. I got it. By right clicking the table I was able to grant privilage

Comment: @justin Cave :Does grant create synonym for tableB in schema A ? Its better we create synonym in  Schema A also .

Comment: @GauravSoni - `GRANT` does not create a synonym, no.  Whether you create a private synonym in schema A, a public synonym, or no synonym and explicitly include the schema name depends heavily on the situation.

Comment: @JustinCave:But its best practise to create synonym  ,why hardcoding the schema name ,and package having invoker rights?,Anyways the other solution also works

Comment: @GauravSoni - I wouldn't say it's a best practice, no.  It's a common practice.  It is often the right solution.  But it's also often the right solution to create a public synonym.  And it's also often the right solution to specify the schema name explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

Follow these steps:

1) Login to schema B
2) Run the statement `GRANT SELECT ON tableB TO A;`
3) In the package make sure the tableB is referenced as B.tableB
4) Compile the package.